# Program to delete digits from text

Tags: c, pointers

This is program that deletes digits in text.  For example `ab98k` -> `abk`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

// move characters starting at cstr+1 to the left by one position
void move_left(char *cstr)
{
    while ((*cstr = *(cstr + 1)))
        ++cstr;
}

// find the first occurrence of a decimal digit.
// return pointer if found, NULL otherwise
char *find_digit(char *cstr)
{
    for ( ; *cstr; ++cstr)
        if (isdigit(*cstr))
            return cstr;

    return NULL; // not found
}

void delete_digits(char *cstr) // remove decimal digits
{
    while (cstr = find_digit(cstr))
        move_left(cstr);
}

int main()
{
// declare array of SZ characters
    enum { SZ = 200 };
    char cstr[SZ];

// prepare format string to read at most SZ-1 characters
    char format[16];
    sprintf(format, "%%%ds", SZ - 1); // ie. "%199s" if SZ == 200

    if (scanf(format, cstr)) // if attempted input was successful
    {
        delete_digits(cstr);
        puts(cstr);
    }
}
```

My questions are: assume I input `ab98k`

```
 void delete_digits( char* cstr ) // remove decimal digits
 {
     while( ( cstr = find_digit(cstr) ) )
         move_left(cstr);
 }
```

In this function "`cstr=find digit(cstr)`", `cstr` is a pointer?

I didn't understand why it has to store the `find_digit` result which is a pointer to the number digit to the pointer `cstr` again?

The result of find_digit function is this, then why have to store it in pointer `cstr` again?

ab98k.
     ^

What is the purpose? And when I change to `{ while( ( find_digit(cstr) ) ) move_left(cstr) ; }` the program seems to error.

My second question:

```
char* find_digit(char* cstr)
{
    for (; *cstr; ++cstr)
        if (isdigit(*cstr))
            return cstr;
    return NULL; // not found
}
```

At the end of this function or when there is no digit, it will return NULL for last word 'k' in 'ab98k' right? It will return null to the `while` in the `delete_digit` function that will terminate it and return to `main`? So the purpose of NULL is to terminate for loop?

another version

```
#include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

  void deldigit(char *str)
 { char *res = str;
 int count=0;
  while(*str!='\0')
  {
  if(*str>='1' && *str<='9')
     { count++;}
  else
     {*(str-count)=*str; /* want this *str after increment to    overwrite *(str-count) */
             }
       str++;}
    *(str - count)= '\0';
   printf("%s",res);
   }
  int main()
  { char str[100];

   printf("inset word");
    scanf("%s",&str);
       deldigit(str);
  return 0;
   }
```

Comment: 1. Because the function is iterating from `cstr` and returning a *new value* which is then assigned to `cstr` (which can be `NULL`).

Comment: What are the rules of engagement?  Are you allowed to use functions from `<string.h>`?  You are reimplementing a number of them.  It isn't the best way to deal with the problem, though.  You are always shrinking and never expanding the string.  You can do the job in a single pass keeping a read pointer that moves every cycle of the loop and a write pointer that moves only when the last character read was not a digit.  Don't forget to null terminate the string.

Comment: @WeatherVane while( ( cstr = find_digit(cstr) )
is this mean the pointer cstr(right) which is result from find digit was given to pointer cstr (left) to replace the pointer that was passed from the calling function in main?

Comment: The pointer was given to the function `find_digit` which iterated from the value it was given, then returned the value where it stopped iterating (a digit was found), or `NULL` (end of string found). The calling function updates `cstr`, otherwise you'll keep repeating what you already did.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler can you give me more hint? what i could think of is to make one variable to count the digit then *(str-count)=*str using this to change the value..

Comment: `void delete_digits(char *cstr) { char *dst = cstr; char *src = cstr; char c; while ((c = *src++) != '\0') { if (!isdigit((unsigned char)c)) *dst++ = c; } *dst = '\0'; }`

Comment: @WeatherVane i know in the first iteration it will return pointer that point 9 in 'ab98k' for example. then will iterate again result in '8k' but at last iteration which is 'k', since there is no digit there, it will return null to delete digit function to terminate the while or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First question: If you pass an array to a function, the function actually receives a pointer to that array. You now can modify this pointer (the pointer itself, not the values pointed at) without modifying the original array at all. If you pass that pointer to another function, you actually pass a copy of that pointer, i. e. if you modify the new pointer in the second function, the pointer of the first function is not affected at all. This is important (among other places) especially for the move_left function being called from within delete_digits!

Then, you need to reassign the pointer to be able to move through the string given:

Now start condition is as follows:

```
 "ab98kk7\0" // for better illustration, I explicitly show the terminating 0 character...
//^ str pointing to here
```

You now search for the first digit in the while loop:

```
 "ab98kk7\0"
//  ^ str pointing to here after first assignment
```

And this is how your string looks after moving left:

```
 "ab8kk7\0\0"
//  ^ str STILL pointing to here
// notice the duplicate \0 at the end...
```

The next assignment in the loop won't modify str, as first letter, seen from pointer's view, is already a digit again, so no change, but after removal, the situation looks like this:

```
 "abkk7\0\0\0"
//  ^ str STILL pointing to here
```

Finding next digit (assignment in while):

```
 "abkk7\0\0\0"
//    ^ str NOW pointing to here
```

OK, lets skip the removal of the last digit... As then no further digit follows, NULL will be assigned to str and we leave the loop...

If you change to the while loop without assignment, you will remove the entire string as long as any new digit is found:

```
 "ab98kk7\0"
//  ^ str pointing to here after first assignment
//^  still pointing to here without assignment!!! (as long as still any digits contained in the string)
```

With my example with the added digit at the end, you would clear out the string entirely...

Second question is short: You are absolutely right...

However, this algorithm is horribly inefficient, as you copy the whole rest of the string each time you eliminate a single character. You can do it much better, if you use two pointers:

```
void eliminateDigits(char* str)
{
    for(char* s = str; *s; ++s)
    {
        if(!isdigit((unsigned char)*s))
            *str++ = *s;
    }
    *str = 0;
}
```

*Addendum* – in response to your comment:

It might help to understand the issue by understanding the nature of pointers and passing them to functions:

Actually, pointers are nothing more than a memory address – stored in a specific number of bytes (how many depends on the architecture you are writing the code for - on modern 64-bit hardware, this is typically eight bytes, older 32-bit hardware used only four of them). If you pass a pointer to a function, you actually copy this address onto the stack into the frame for this function.

Let's imagine the stack now:

```
- return value of main (place holder!)
- argv (assuming cdecl calling convention -> arguments placed in reverse order)
- argc
- main's cstr, array of 200 bytes
- main's format, array of 16 bytes
```

Calling delete_digits:

```
- return value of main (place holder!)
- argv
- argc
- main's cstr, array of 200 bytes
- main's format, array of 16 bytes
- return value of delete_digits (place holder!)
- delete_digits' cstr, pointer to main's cstr, 8 bytes
```

Within find_digit, you can simply add these few lines to above:

```
- return value of find_digit (place holder!)
- find_digit's cstr, copy of delete_digits' pointer, thus pointing to main's cstr, too
```

Situation is as follows:

```
ab98k\0      (main's array)
^            (pointer of delete_digits)
^            (pointer of find_digit)
```

find_digit (repeatedly) modifies its own variant of the pointer:

```
ab98k\0      (main's array)
^            (pointer of delete_digits)
  ^          (pointer of find_digit before returning)
```

Without assignment, the last pointer on the stack is just removed (simply remove the last line above)! Only if you *do* assign, delete_digits's pointer will be adjusted, too:

```
ab98k\0      (main's array)
  ^          (pointer of delete_digits)
```

Same applies now for move_left:

```
ab98k\0      (main's array)
  ^          (pointer of delete_digits)
  ^          (pointer of move_left)
```

move_left advances the pointer - by dereferencing it, it accesses, though, the address the pointer points to – which is the array of main(!):

```
ab88k\0      (main's array)
  ^          (pointer of delete_digits)
   ^         (pointer of move_left)

ab8kk\0      (main's array)
  ^          (pointer of delete_digits)
    ^        (pointer of move_left)

ab8k\0\0     (main's array)
  ^          (pointer of delete_digits)
    ^        (pointer of move_left before returning)
```

Notice that the delete_digits' pointer was not touched at all here (as wasn't either while find_digit modified its version...).

Comment: Strictly strictly you should ensure that the argument to `isdigit()` is an `unsigned char` converted to `int`, not a (possibly signed, possibly negative) plain `char` that is converted to `int`.  Otherwise, the one pass algorithm is exactly the way to go.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Assuming ASCII, it wouldn't matter. Getting away from, it gets complicated anyway as we need to consider encoding. What about multibyte utf8-numerals from other languages??? Still, I added the cast...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler By the way - what about systems where int and char have the same size??? I happened once to code for such one (TI DSP), both char and int having 16 bit...

Comment: On systems where `sizeof(char) == sizeof(int)`, you are less likely to need the cast.  It gets tricky.  The `isvwxyz()` functions take an `int` argument which is either an `unsigned char` (converted to `int`) or `EOF`.  On such systems, what is the value of `EOF`?  It has to be negative.  It is traditionally `-1` but that is not mandated.  There are design issues to resolve there.  Multi-byte codesets should be processed by code that is multi-byte aware — wide characters or UTF-8, UTF-16, etc.  The crucial point is that the byte 0xC4 is not passed as a negative number.

Comment: And the 'strictly strictly' prefix was an indication that this is a niggling detail often overlooked (except by the default compiler options I use — and since I use `-Werror` too, my code doesn't compile if I get lazy).  _[…time passes…]_  Hmmm; I just went to check that statement, and for some reason, I'm no longer getting the error.  It probably has something to do with the `<ctype.h>` header defining: `__DARWIN_CTYPE_TOP_inline int isdigit(int _c) { return (__isctype(_c, _CTYPE_D)); }`.  This is macOS Sierra 10.12.5 and XCode 8.3.2.  I'm sure it used to generate complaints in times past.

Comment: why the while loop without assignment point to the first char and not the fund one although it has called the find_digit function? and your program much better only copy the non digit value to another pointer

Comment: @Aconcagua { while( ( find_digit(cstr) ) ) move_left(cstr) ; } -> why this remove first character and not from the one found/return from the find_digit function? since the find digit function result is suppose to be pointer that point first digit? can you explain a bit more?

Comment: @fiksx Passing a pointer means passing it as a **copy**. Both delete_digit and find_digit have their own version of such a pointer, and thus, although find_digit modifies its own pointer, this won't change the delete_digit's version at all. So, if you do not re-assign the pointer in delete_digit, it won't be modified and thus will stay where it was before - i. e. the start of the string...

Comment: @fiksx Actually, you *can* find_digit let modify the delete_digit's version of the pointer. But for that, you have to pass a pointer to pointer to find_digit: `char* find_digit(char** cstr)` (notice the double asterix) and call it from delete_digits via `find_digit(&cstr)`. Inside find_digit, you need to dereference cstr once more on every occurence: `for (; **cstr; ++*cstr)` etc.

Comment: @aconcagua hello thanks for the further explanation!!!!!! ,,in in conclusion if the while dont have assignment "while(find_digit(cstr)", the return copy from find_digit is just to determine the condition of the while loop as long as not NULL  , but the pointer that pass to the move_left function is the one that delete_digit has and it doesnt have any relation with the return copy pointer from find_digit,

Comment: @aconcagua but if i use "while(cstr=find_digit(cstr)" the return pointer from move_left will be insert to cstr again so it will change the pointer in delete digit!!!! i wonder about our code too, is there algorithm behind it?? or you just made it according to your logic then implement it with c syntax?

Comment: @aconcagua and in your code version: the first iteration after set both pointer point the same front word,, if non digit *str++ = *s; assign pointer s to str; then increment str by 1
then after the execution of for loop,,++src in for loop, is ++src and src++ has same result in this for loop?
so basically you made s as pointer to evaluate if there is a digit, then move the non digit to *str then print it  ,, is there algorithm behind it.. (seems funn question but just wondering),, i can think another beginner version .. i will put it in edit

Comment: @fiksx Have a close look - you pass cstr (within delete_digits) to move_left - again as a copy! So original cstr (delete_digits) won't be modified within move_left. What is changed is the array where both cstr pointers point to, though. This is why you see the changes from move_left within delete_digits.

Comment: There is no difference between ++s and s++, as long as you do not evaluate the result. In the for loop, I don't, so select whichever you prefer (if you ever get to C++, this is not necesarily the same there, though...). Different is the if body: `*str++`: str is dereferenced with its value before incrementation, which is distinct from `*++str`.

Comment: @aconcagua i know that in delete digit the pointer is still point the first number that was find, third position, assume "ab98k", as the move_left will return the array value that has been move left so thats why i see change there right?? the point here the pointer is a copy.. so it doesnt effect the delete digit pointer, but the result change in the array will affect it (?)

Comment: @fiksx Errm - move_left returns void, i. e. nothing at all... Apart from that, I think you got it now. Imagine you have a video telephone, and you called a friend Alice from there. Imagine could have a copy of your phone and hand it to another person Bob. Bob now tells Alice to turn round (change the original array). Of course, you see Alice in changed position, too. Now Bob calls another person Charles (changes the pointer). Your own phone is still connected to Alice... Not sure if a nice example, but couldn't imagine up something better.

Comment: @aconcagua thanks i kinda got it!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!              supose make pointer call pdigit     ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,                                                                                           char * pdigit = find_digit(cstr);
while( pdigit )
{
  cstr = pdigit;
  move_left(cstr);
  pdigit = find_digit(cstr);
}                                                                                                                        but in this code what the purpose of making pointer here??

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
{ while( ( find_digit(cstr) ) ) move_left(cstr) ; }
```

removes first character (not the one found) from the string if find_digit(cstr) is != NULL

it is easier to understand if you add a temporary variable

```
char *tmp;
while( ( tmp = find_digit(cstr) ) ) move_left(tmp) ;
```

but this version will be less effective as it searches for a digit from the beginning of the string and the original version

```
    while (cstr = find_digit(cstr))
         move_left(cstr);
```

only from the last found.

Comment: { while( ( find_digit(cstr) ) ) move_left(cstr) ; } -> why this remove first character and not from the one found? since the find digit function result is suppose to be pointer that point first digit?

Comment: because cstr always points to the first character.  { while( (cstr = find_digit(cstr) ) ) move_left(cstr) ; }  -> after every iteration cstr points to the digit found

Comment: but the  
 
{ while( ( find_digit(cstr) ) ) move_left(cstr) ; }  -> find_digit will return pointer cstr that point to the digit that was found or not?

Comment: cstr is a local variable in find_digit and  in the scope of while it will be another one (they have the same names but different scopes). This while should be != NULL to avoid warnings.

Comment: is this mean result from find_digit function is suppose "98k" that will be return to the find_digit, but since the condition of while is while !=NULL,move_left (cstr ), the cstr here in delete_digit function point the first word, then will loop the while until it NULL.. (?)

Answer (score 0):

The function `find_digit` returns a pointer which send this pointer to a variable cstr which have NOTHING to do with the cstr in its own function. Each cstr is unique in its own function.

So basically if the symbol is not a digit, it returns NULL and the while loop in delete_digit stops.

The program will error if you dont assign cstr in the delete_digit function because the cstr is used inside the while loop.

This answer your second question.

Comment: { while( ( find_digit(cstr) ) ) move_left(cstr) ; } ->  find digit function result is suppose to be pointer that point first digit, then why it removes first char..

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just do...

```
string removeDigits(const string& str) {

   string noDigits;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
       if(!(isDigit(str[i]))) 
          noDigits += str[i] + ""; 
    }
return noDigits;
}
```

While isDigit is some helper function that checks if the char is [0-9]

Comment: Additionally, there is no operator+ accepting a plain char and a classic c string (`str[i] + "";`). You could, though, simply do `noDigits += str[i];` Anyway, for this case, I'd prefer the new range based for loop: `for(char c : str) { if(isdigit(c)) {} }`